# Does a class E airspace still exist when the associated control tower is closed?

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, airspace, class-e-airspace

An airport tower closes at 1600 hours:

- Does the extension (class E from surface up) airspace becomes non existing?
- Can I fly through since the tower is closed?

Comment: Maybe, when it says "closes at 1600 hours", is that local time, or UTC? Have you read the AF/D (now called the Chart Supplement)? It may be E or G depending on what the CS says.

Comment: It depends on the jurisdiction.

Comment: Let me add a little more info. This is a helicopter manufacturing plant (Sikorsky ).. When the tower closes ,all flying is suspended. It's a class D airport with the E extension.  Closes at local time.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Which country or regulations are you asking about? And if you have a specific airport as an example, please tell us which one it is. It's best to edit your question to add new information.

Comment: In the US, what happens to airspace when the Tower is closed can also depend on the weather reporting available -- typically E if there is an AWOS/ASOS, G otherwise. But I don't think this is a rule, always check the A/FD.

Comment: @quietflyer almost certainly https://www.airnav.com/airport/06FA

Comment: Re my 3-20-2022 edit of Q- ok, maybe he really did mean when the AIRPORT is closed, in the title-- but since that was only clear from a comment, not from the question, and since the question and title ought to match, I'll refrain from rolling it back. If someone wants to also know what happens when the *airport* is closed they could add another part to the question, or ask a new one. Plus, it's not really clear that the airport is actually closed when the tower is closed--if the above airport suggestion is correct, AIRNAV page says "WHEN ATCT CLSD, FOR CD CTC PALM BEACH APCH AT 561-275-1430"

Answer (score 4):

> Does the extension (class E from surface up) airspace becomes non
> existing?

It depends on whether the Class D airspace at the surface reverts to surface-level Class E airspace, or to Class G airspace (usually with a Class E floor above, at 700' AGL or 1200' AGL), when the tower closes.

If the Class D converts to surface-level Class E airspace, then the extensions remain in place as surface-level Class E airspace.

If the Class D converts to Class G (usually with a Class E floor above, at 700' AGL or 1200' AGL), so do the extensions.

This is clarified by the following content in the "Airspace" entry in the "Legend" section of the "Chart Supplement" (formerly "Airport/Facilities Directory") :

> NOTE: AIRSPACE SVC "TIMES" INCLUDE ALL ASSOCIATED ARRIVAL EXTENSIONS.
> Surface area arrival extensions for instrument approaches become part
> of the primary core surface area.  These extensions may be be either
> Class D or Class E airspace and are effective concurrent with the time
> of the primary core surface area.  For example, when a part-time Class
> C, Class D, or Class E surface area defaults to Class G, the
> associated arrival extensions will default to Class E at the same
> time.   When a part-time Class C or Class D surface area defaults to
> Class E, the arrival extensions will remain in effect as Class E
> airspace.

The full content of the "Airspace" entry (item 30, on the page labelled p.26) in the "Legend" section of the Chart Supplement (Northeast region, issue effective beginning 3-24-2022) is attached below.

In the case where the Class D converts to Class G and the "extensions" therefore vanish, be aware that there is some [slightly misleading content in the Legend of the Chart Supplement-- the Legend indicates that the actual Airspace entries for each airport also clarify whether the overlying Class E airspace begins at 700' or 1200' AGL, but that's not really true.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91301/when-did-this-content-first-appear-in-the-airspace-entry-of-the-legend-secti)  You have to figure that out by looking at the sectional chart.

At any rate, you won't have any trouble telling from the Chart Supplement whether the core Class D airspace converts to surface-level Class E airspace (and the "extensions" therefore remain), or converts to Class G airspace (and the "extensions" therefore vanish.)

You *should* be able to tell the same information from the sectional chart itself.  ***(***Caution: this only works for airports that do have surface-level Class E extensions***, not for those that lack surface-level Class E extensions.)  Here's how the system is supposed to work:

***If*** the Class D airspace reverts all the way to Class G, then the sectional chart is supposed to depict that there is a change in status of the core Class D airspace ***and*** the surface-level Class E extensions.  Because ***both*** are reverting to Class G.  This is accomplished via the use of the phrase "See Chart Supplement for D/E(surf) eff hrs".

***If*** the Class D airspace reverts to surface-level Class E airspace, then the sectional chart is supposed to depict that there is a change ***only*** in the status of the core Class D airspace.  Because the status of the "extensions" is ***not*** changing.  This is accomplished via the use of the phrase "See Chart Supplement for D eff hrs".

(For airports where are no surface-level Class E "extensions" to the Class D airspace, the latter phrase is *always* used, hence the word of caution. In this case the use of this phrase on the sectional chart must *not* be taken as an indication that the Class D airspace reverts to surface-level Class E airspace, rather than Class G airspace, when the tower is closed.  Instead, the pilot *must* consult the Chart Supplement.)

There have been some errors in the past when this system was not uniformly adopted, and the former phrase on the sectional chart was incorrectly applied to cases where the Class D airspace reverted to surface-level Class E airspace (and the "extensions" therefore remained as surface-level Class E airspace).<sup>1</sup>  Some of these inconsistencies would certainly have been present at the time that the question was originally asked.  Most or all of these cases have apparently been recently corrected.<sup>2</sup>  In all cases, the Chart Supplement itself *did* correctly explain the status of the airspace.

> Can I fly through since the tower is closed?

You don't normally need to talk to anyone to fly through Class E airspace -- including the surface-level Class E "extensions", or the core surface-level Class E airspace areas that actually include the airports for which they are designated -- unless you can't maintain the relevant VFR cloud clearance and visibility requirements, in which case you might consider requesting a Special VFR clearance.  Note that [FAR 91.155(c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.155) prohibits operation below a cloud ceiling that is lower than 1000' AGL in Class E airspace that extends all the way down to ground level, unless you obtain a Special VFR clearance.  (There is actually some ambiguity around whether or not Special VFR clearance would even be valid for a surface-level Class E "extension".  For more on this, see the links near the end of [this related ASE answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/92260/34686).)

[image]

Footnotes:

1,2) See ACM Charting Group Minutes here -- https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/acf/media/RDs/21-01-360_Contolled_Airspace_Effective_Hours.pdf .  See also [this related ASE answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54048/what-class-is-the-airspace-at-kgcn-when-the-tower-is-closed/75377#75377).

Comment: Re "Most or of all of these cases have apparently recently been corrected"-- near superscript "2" -- actually, KNHK and KNTU still have the faulty notation on the sectional chart, reading "See NOTAMs/Supplement for Class D/E (sfc) eff hrs", even though their airspace is actually in effect 24/7. Latest chart checked: Washington sectional chart effective beginning March 24 2022.  But I now understand that this is scheduled to be corrected in the sectional chart effective beginning May 19 2022.

Comment: Might be more clear to say -- "including the surface-level Class E "extensions", AS WELL as the core surface-level Class E airspace areas that actually include the airports for which they are designated -- ..."

Comment: Triple asterisks visible in answer were supposed to be formatting indications and should be deleted

Comment: Link in long string of of underlined (linking) text beginning with "slightly misleading content..." links to wrong ASE answer.  Supposed to go here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/86583/34686